# C# Elastic search connection pool implementation facing issue

Tags: nest

Error: "Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccesful low level call on HEAD:Audit exception in step 2 PingFailure:\r\nElasticsearch.Net.PipelineException:   An error occurred trying to establish a connection with the specified node.\r\n "

```
private static ElasticClient GetESClient(Uri[] nodes, string username, string password)
        {
           var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(nodes);
            var setting = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
                               .SniffOnConnectionFault(false)
                               .SniffOnStartup(false)
.SniffLifeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).DisableDirectStreaming()
                               .BasicAuthentication(username, password)
                               .MaximumRetries(5);
setting.DefaultIndex(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearch_val"].ToString());
            var esClient = new ElasticClient(setting);
            return esClient;
        }
```

Comment: That's the error message, but what are you trying to do? Do you have a sample of your code? From the error message, there is a problem pinging a node in the cluster, but you'll need to provide more details

Comment: Yes I have added the sample code